# why do you need to call TFRecordDataset.repeat()?

Tags: tensorflow

The idea is the run the entire dataset over the number epochs. Obviously, the dataset is used repeatedly. What exactly does calling repeat() do?

Answer (score 2):

The whole purpose of the `tf.data.TFRecordDataset().repeat(num_epochs)`, is the repeat the dataset `num_epoch` times in memory, so that you can iterate over the dataset `num_epoch` times with a `tf.data.TFRecordDataset().make_one_shot_iterator()`. Please check the example below (Please note that I am using `tf.data.Dataset()` because it to demonstrate the usage of `.repeat(num_epochs)`).

```
X = np.random.rand(10,2)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(X)
dataset = dataset.batch(5)
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(iterator.get_next())
    sess.run(iterator.get_next())
    # The third time this is called it throws an exception
    sess.run(iterator.get_next())
```

Now, if we do `tf.data.Dataset().repeat(num_epochs)`, we can iterate over the dataset `num_epochs` times.

```
X = np.random.rand(10,2)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(X)
dataset = dataset.repeat(2)
dataset = dataset.batch(5)
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(iterator.get_next())
    sess.run(iterator.get_next())
    sess.run(iterator.get_next())
    sess.run(iterator.get_next())
    # Now, the fifth time it will throw an exception
    sess.run(iterator.get_next())
```

However, I would propose to sidestep using `tf.data.Dataset().make_one_shot_iterator()`. Thing is, this iterator is good if you want to iterate over the dataset once, or a limited number of times. Therefore, I would propose using `tf.data.Dataset().make_initializable_iterator()`.

```
X = np.random.rand(10,2)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(X)
dataset = dataset.batch(5)
iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Initialize the iterator to iterate over the dataset
    sess.run(iterator.initializer)
    sess.run(iterator.get_next())
    sess.run(iterator.get_next())
    # Once done, initialize it again
    sess.run(iterator.initializer)
    sess.run(iterator.get_next())
    sess.run(iterator.get_next())
```

As you can see, with the initializable iterator, you can just go over the dataset, and once you are done, reinitialize it again to start a new epoch. Here is a convenient way of doing that.

```
num_epochs = 3
X = np.random.rand(10,2)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(X)
dataset = dataset.batch(5)
iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    for e in range(num_epochs):
        sess.run(iterator.initializer)
        try:
            while True:
                sess.run(iterator.get_next()) 
                # Or do whatever you want with the batch
        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
            print(f"Epoch {e+1} finished, starting over!")
            pass
```